# How to define regex in php to check strings

Tags: php, regex

I've been using following regex to search the string containing *"function(...){}"*:

```
/(?<=:)"function\((?:(?!}").)*}"/
```

The string might also contain "function ()" - space between function and bracket "()"

how can regex be defined to check "function()..." or " function ()..."?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an optional space in the appropriate place:

```
/(?<=:)"function *\((?:(?!}").)*}"/
```

`" *"` matches zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?<=:)"function\s*\((?:(?!}").)*}"/
```

here \s* means zero or more ...occurrence of space...

(you are missing `{` to match?)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<=:)"function[ ]*\((?:(?!}").)*}"/
```

This would do it.